# Javascript Promise resolve value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return a value from a promise, but I can't. Why it doesn't work?

I get `Promise { <pending> }` output only.

function

```
  function username() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      user.where('id', req.id).fetch().then(function (data) {
        data = data.toJSON();
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }
```

variable

```
var r = username().then(function (a) {
    return a.username;
  });

  console.log(r);
```

If I remove `return` and put `console.log(a.username)`, it works, but it's not the result I want. I want to put returned value inside `r`.

EDIT #1

I need to pass my returned values into a view (like below), so I must be able to access them outside of the then() chain.

```
res.render("frontend/index", {
    value1 : value1,
    value2 : value2,
    value3 : value3
  });
```

EDIT #2

I'm using Express.js

Now I get `"Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."` error, I hope it's more clear now. When a user tries to access a page, I query the database and pass variables to a view, but there are more than one operation per view (username, post info, comments, etc).

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {

  function username() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      user.where('id', req.id).fetch().then(function (data) {
        data = data.toJSON();
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }

  username().then(function (b) {
    res.render('backend/index', {
      username: b.username
    });
  });

  function post() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      post.where('id', req.params.postId).fetch().then(function (data) {
        data = data.toJSON();
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }

  post().then(function (a) {
    res.render('backend/index', {
      post: a.post
    });
  });

};
```

Comment: AFAK then() retuns a promise, so r is a promise, not its result.

Comment: _"want to put returned value inside r"_ What is next process for `r` ?

Comment: You cannot access the values outside of the .then chain.

Comment: _"so I must be able to access them outside of the then() chain."_ Why can `res.render` not be called within `.then()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.then()` function returns a promise only. Here in above code variable `r` is nothing but a promise reference object.

If you want to use the returned response from the promise, this is how you will do it -

```
username().then(function (a) {

   console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
   // you will need to use the response returned from server here..
  // display in view or something else
  res.render("frontend/index", {
      value1 : a.value1,
      value2 : a.value2,
      value3 : a.value3
 });

 });
```

Returning a value from inside a promise thenable function will only return a promise and not the value.

You will need to wait till all the promises are resolved and then only send the response from the server. Once a response is sent, you can not send it again and hence the error `headers...`.

Updated answer as per modified question -

```
 exports.index = function (req, res) {

    function username() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            user.where('id', req.id).fetch().then(function (data) {
                data = data.toJSON();
                resolve(data);
            });
        });
    }

    function post() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            post.where('id', req.params.postId).fetch().then(function (data) {
                data = data.toJSON();
                resolve(data);
            });
        });
    }

    username().then(function (b) {

        post().then(function (a) {

            res.render('backend/index', {
                post: a.post,
                username: b.username
            });
        });

    });
};
```

Comment: You can call `res.render(...)` inside the then function also. Basically that should be the way.

Comment: If you want to do anything with the returned response, it should be called inside `.then(function(){  // here  })` only...

Comment: Thanks, but what if I'm dealing with multiple functions (username, posts, categories, etc) to serve a view? Do I need to use res.render for each function?

Comment: If different functions involve or depend on different promises then yes.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I don't know whether I should ask a new question or not, so here it goes. Could you please check edit #2 out?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to restrict the usage of the value to functions passed to `.then`. There is no other logical way to assert that the value of `r` has been assigned.

```
var r;
username().then(function(a) {
  r = a.username;
  // use r here

  // resolve promise with value of username
  return r;
}).then(function(username) {
  // or use it here
});
```

Comment: the very first time variable `r` will log as an undefined.

Comment: Yes, `console.log` will be called before the function resolves, only way to force it would be to put it inside another `then()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Try performing next process where `fulfilled` value of `r` is used inside of `.then()` to access asynchronous returned value from `Promise` `r`

```
var r = username().then(function (a) {
    return a.username;
});

r.then(function(data) {
  // `data` : `r` return value
  // do stuff with `data` here
});
```